# .Net Core 2.2 C# HttpClient.GetAsync stop working after sometimes on high load?

Tags: c#, performance, httpclient

I'm working on a .NET Core 2.2 Service Project, my project should connect to another services.

I register my HttpClient as a singleton in startup as follows:

```
public class HttpClientIbsApiGetWay : HttpClient
{
    public HttpClientIbsApiGetWay()
    {
        DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
        DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/json");
    }
}

services.AddSingleton(provider =>
{
    return new HttpClientIbsApiGetWay
    {
        BaseAddress = new Uri("someUrl"),
        Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 10)
    };
});
```

and use it as follows:

```
private static async Task<string> GetErrorMessage(HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage)
{
    var contentString = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var errorMessage = $"{(int)httpResponseMessage.StatusCode} {httpResponseMessage.StatusCode.ToString()}";
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(contentString)) return errorMessage;
    return $"{errorMessage}: " + contentString;
}

protected async Task<T> SendIbsGetRequestAsync<T>(string apiUrl)
{   
    using (var httpResponseMessage = await HttpClient.GetAsync(apiUrl))
    {
        if (!httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            throw new Exception(await GetErrorMessage(httpResponseMessage));
        return await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>();
    }
}
```

If I send ~2 request/sec It's OK, but if I send ~4 request/sec continuously in 30 seconds my application stop working and CPU usage go up 100% without any response from my application and I get this error from IIS:

> The CGI application did not return a valid set of HTTP errors.
>
> A server acting as a proxy or gateway was unable to process the request due to an error in a parent gateway.

I debug my code and changed it as follows:

```
protected async Task<T> SendIbsGetRequestAsync<T>(string apiUrl)
{   
    return default(T);
    //using (var httpResponseMessage = await HttpClient.GetAsync(apiUrl))
    //{
    //  if (!httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    //      throw new Exception(await GetErrorMessage(httpResponseMessage));
    //  return await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>();
    //}
}
```

It worked well.
Also, I test destination server on "some url", It's OK and response on high load.
So I'm dead sure the problem are commented lines.

How can I find the problem?

**EDIT:**
I monitor my server in duration of high loading. With start sending request to server, memory usage become grows and memory is not released upon stop sending requests.

Comment: Are you doing any locking? Because using a singleton object from multiple threads...

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Not at all

Comment: It is a server side error, not a client side error. The server is simply telling you that "something wrong with you requests" (possibly you are making too many requests per second)

Comment: @KirillPolishchuk But my application was down and not response to another requests.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.2 (HttpClientFactory).

Comment: thread pool starvation?